# Deploy Craft CMS site to VPS for the first time

Tags: craft3, deployment, nitro, docker

I'm completely new to deploying a Craft CMS to a web server and don't know where to start. I have self taught experience in front-end development but I'm lost when it comes to anything deployment/server based.

Prior to building this Craft CMS website I had never used Craft CMS, however throughout the process I have managed to find enough documentation to help me, however I've become very stuck when it comes to deployment.

My current situation is...

– As per documentation from Craft CMS I have created my site and used Craft Nitro and Docker to run it locally. Link to documentation here https://craftcms.com/docs/getting-started-tutorial/#why-craft-cms

– Below is a screenshot of the Containers visible in Docker.

[image]

– Below is a screenshot of the Images I have in Docker.
[image]

– I have purchased a VPS with Digital Ocean.

My ultimate aim is to understand how I get my website from my local machine on to the VPS. Any help or guidance would be really appreciated.

Thanks
Sam

Answer (score 1):

Andrew welch had an in depth article on deployments here https://nystudio107.com/blog/executing-atomic-deployments/

It may be a little advanced, but it's the blue print for the holy grail of repeatable deployment process.